# Hibernate validator spring configuration is successful - but localized message are not loading

Tags: spring, hibernate, localization, hibernate-validator

I have configured Hibernate validator with spring and it is working fine. Validation is performed correctly. And I can see the error messages correctly after wrong input is made.

But the problem is validation messages load only for English locale, but I have setup for Arabic language also. I have 2 error message files (ValidationMessages_ar_SA.properties and ValidationMessages_en_US.properties and also the default one ValidationMessages.properties). After this english error message loads correctly, whereas in Arabic, it shows an empty message.

Here are the settings:

```
@Size(max=50, message="${javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}")
private String benefName = "";


<bean id="validator"
  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
   <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>


<bean id="messageSource" parent="messageSourceAbstract"
    class="sa.alrajhi.retail.context.support.CMSReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:ValidationMessages</value>
            <value>classpath:i18n/messages</value>
            <value>classpath:i18n/beneficiaries/regionCode</value>
            <value>classpath:i18n/cityCode</value>          
            <value>classpath:i18n/beneficiaries/bankCode</value>
            <value>classpath:i18n/emails</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: can you update your configurations

Comment: what does sa.alrajhi.retail.context.support.CMSReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource class do?

Comment: It allows to pick message resources from the CMS repository, we use Alfresco.